# .htacces is not working with CodeIgniter 1.7.3, php 5.3

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I tried to hide the index.php with .htaccess, CI 1.7.3 and php 5.3 and got an error 404.
But it’s working fine on my development server which is having php 5.2 and rest of all are the same configuration, i developed my application with HMVC and my .htaccess is

```
    RewriteEngine on
    Options -Indexes
    RewriteBase /myapp/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myapp/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Anybody suggest me the way how can i resolve this issue should i upgrade my CI version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /myapp/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5})$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ myapp/index.php?/$1 [L]
```

It might be that your .htaccess thinks it should open `myapp/myapp/index.php` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Open config.php from system/application/config directory

and replace

```
$config['index_page'] = “index.php” by $config['index_page'] = “”
```

Create a “.htaccess” file in the root of CodeIgniter directory

and add the following lines.

```
    RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

In some case the default setting for uri_protocol does not work properly.

To solve this problem just replace

```
`$config['uri_protocol'] = “AUTO”`
```

by

```
 $config['uri_protocol'] = “REQUEST_URI”
```

from system/application/config/config.php

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether your apache rewrite module is included in your server and enabled rewrite rule in the apache configuration file.

Comment: it's already enabled in my .htaccess file but it's not working

Comment: please check your server about the rewrite module not in your .htaccess file